# unbuild. Remove a built package

Tags: 11.10, compiling, vim

I was having issue with the vim-gnome package and command-t with vim not compiling with the system ruby. So I built vim with.

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
cd vim
./configure --enable-rubyinterp
make
sudo make install
```

But I made a mistake. when I did vim --version | grep ruby I realised my error.
I had forgotten to turn off rvm before compiling.

```
   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/renshaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib -L/home/renshaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib -lruby -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/home/renshaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib
```

But I can't get apt-get remove it and I cannot see vim in /usr/bin/. It still runs if I type vim, but how do I remove it so I can compile it properly?

Comment: It should be in `/usr/local`

Comment: using which vim you can at first find out where the executable is located which is invoked.I suggest to read the README or INSTALL files which usually are in the project archives. Further it should as well be possible to just run make install again after a new compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the commenter's (jrg) suggested it's likely to be in `/usr/local`.  You don't need to uninstall before recompiling and reinstalling though.  When you install again it will simply overwrite the previous version.

You can normally run `./configure --help` to see what the options available are, like the install path (normally labeled prefix and set to `/usr/local` I believe).